# Node.js + puppeteer failing in docker: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb

Tags: node.js

i am having a node.js application which i want to run in docker-compose

here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app

RUN npm install --save app

COPY . /app

CMD ["yarn", "add", "puppeteer"]
```

and here is my compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  insta-bot:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    entrypoint: ["node", "/app/example.js"]
```

when i do docker-compose up it container fails with this error:

```
Error: Failed to launch chrome!
my-service  | /app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686378/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

Resolved my issue with adding to dockerfile this:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

and for puppeteer launch in script this:

```
 browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true,args: ['--no-sandbox','--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });
```